# Android Facebook HashKey Invalid

Tags: android, facebook

I was having some problem with the key has for Android Facebook. So basically I got my key hash as `+J+3yf/mrgPgKeg1llIttpSjcws=` and my facebook app ID `1596000240623060`:

[image]

The key hash inside was using the correct one which is this: +J+3yf/mrgPgKeg1llIttpSjcws=

However, when I try to run from my Android, when I goes to log in page, it tells me invalid hah key UfL1O1VVSEn88zyVkNdltm8X5bM does not match any store hash key. But I did not use that. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

I am putting these code at the page onCreate() where I called the facebook login:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getActivity().getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "nyp.edu.eneighbourhood", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

As from the cmd, I am doing the same way as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the development hash key with the debug.keystore, and if you have a release key generate the release hash key.

According with the Facebook Doc:

**Development Hash**:

On Mac:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

On Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**Release Hash Key**:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

NOTE: If you change your development machine or eclipse version the debug.keystore changes too, so you must generate the hashkey again.

Good Luck!

Comment: I get the +J+3yf/mrgPgKeg1llIttpSjcws= hash key from cmd. But then when I run in codes to get the hash key, I am getting UfL1O1VVSEn88zyVkNdltm8X5bM. So which one should I use?

Comment: How are you generating the those codes? Both in code and cmd

Comment: Any ideas? I am confused

Comment: Ok i see, but the hash key should be the same in code and cmd, are you using the correct keystore?

Comment: When I used the UfL1O1VVSEn88zyVkNdltm8X5bM as key hash, it does not show any invalid hashkey message but then, when my button onclick, it just show the facebook status bar with an empty page and load for a while n close the intent itself. Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Is it because I logged in previously and that's why?

Comment: Yep, there are two possible reasons, you are logged in or if you are generated an signed apk with a release key store and you haven't registered the release hash key in the settings section in Facebook development dashboard.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by signed apk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67517/discussion-between-ollie-strevel-and-i-was-so-lost).

Comment: I've followed the link you provided but I am getting another error. Please help me take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616501/android-facebook-session